# SQL Server 2008 Reporting: Sum of Max of group

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, reporting-services, sum, max

I have a table like this in the report designer:

```
Category:       1     2       3      4   Total
Max Amount:     x     y       z      c     ?
```

I need to get the total of Max Amount, but expressions will not let me take Sum(Max(amount)), and the add total is disabled for this cell.

The max amount row is an expression that takes the max of each category.  The source data has repeated values, so I just take the max.  For example:

```
Category    Amount
    1         4.6
    1         4.6
    1         4.6
    2          5
    3          4
```

Other columns in the table are different, but amount will be the same so I cannot only select distinct values.

Comment: What sql version are you using?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Maybe something like this:

```
SELECT
    SUM(t1.maxAmout)
FROM
(
    SELECT
        MAX(t.Amout) AS maxAmout,
        t.Category
    FROM
        yourTable AS t
    GROUP BY
        t.Category
) AS t1
```

You can also do it like this. If you are using sql server 2005+:

```
SELECT
    pvt.[1],
    pvt.[2],
    pvt.[3],
    (
        pvt.[1]+
        pvt.[2]+
        pvt.[3]
    ) AS Total
FROM
(
    SELECT
        t.Category,
        t.Amout
    FROM
        yourTable AS t
) AS SourceTable
PIVOT
(
    MAX(Amout)
    FOR Category IN([1],[2],[3])
) AS pvt
```

**EDIT**

If you have a 1000 categories. Then a dynamic pivot would be the best solution. So like this:

**Test data**

```
CREATE TABLE #T
    (
        Category INT,
        Amout FLOAT
    )

INSERT INTO #T
VALUES
    (1,4.6),
    (1,4.6),
    (1,4.6),
    (2,5),
    (3,4)
```

**Unique column names**

```
DECLARE @cols VARCHAR(MAX)
DECLARE @colsTotal VARCHAR(MAX)
;WITH CTE
AS
(
    SELECT
        ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY t.Category ORDER BY t.Amout) AS RowNbr,
        t.*
    FROM
        #T AS t
)
SELECT  @cols = COALESCE(@cols + ','+QUOTENAME(Category),
                     QUOTENAME(Category)),
        @colsTotal=COALESCE(@colsTotal + '+ISNULL('+QUOTENAME(Category)+',0)',
                     'ISNULL('+QUOTENAME(Category)+',0)')
FROM 
    CTE
WHERE
    CTE.RowNbr=1
ORDER BY 
    Category
```

**Dynamic pivot**

```
DECLARE @query NVARCHAR(4000)=
N'SELECT
    '+@cols+',
    (
        '+@colsTotal+'
    ) AS Total
FROM
(
    SELECT
        t.Category,
        t.Amout
    FROM
        #T AS t
) AS SourceTable
PIVOT
(
    MAX(Amout)
    FOR Category IN('+@cols+')
) AS pvt'

EXECUTE(@query)
```

Comment: what if there are 1000 categories? just curious if this is the best solution

Comment: @paabobo: if there is 1000 category is would still do a pivot. But in that case a dynamic pivot. If it is the best solution or not. It all depends on the database schema. But on the plus side is that you only have to group by ones. That has to be performance vise much faster. I think in this case a pivot can be positive for the performance.

Comment: @rsoni : Remember to upvote the answer you think are good. That gives us all a warm fuzzy feeling :P

Comment: If 1000 categories means 1000 columns then there will not be enough room in an `nvarchar(4000)` variable to hold the entire script.

Comment: @Arion : I see, it seems like that will work fine...1 vote for you

Answer (score 2):

```
WITH
  aggregate
AS
(
  SELECT
    category,
    MAX(amount)  AS max_amount
  FROM
    yourTable
  GROUP BY
    category
)
SELECT
  MAX(CASE WHEN category = 1 THEN max_amount ELSE NULL END)    AS [1],
  MAX(CASE WHEN category = 2 THEN max_amount ELSE NULL END)    AS [2],
  MAX(CASE WHEN category = 3 THEN max_amount ELSE NULL END)    AS [3],
  MAX(CASE WHEN category = 4 THEN max_amount ELSE NULL END)    AS [4],
  SUM(max_amount)                                              AS [total]
FROM
  aggregate
```

Answer (score 0):

The following returns a single value:

```
SELECT DISTINCT SUM(MAX(Amount)) OVER ()
FROM atable
GROUP BY Category
```

You could use this as a subquery calculating the value of the `Total` column.

Alternatively, `TOP (1)` could be used instead of `DISTINCT` (don't know why I couldn't think of it before):

```
SELECT TOP (1) SUM(MAX(Amount)) OVER ()
FROM atable
GROUP BY Category
```